# OpenGL ES 3.0 occlusion query always result false

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I am trying for occlusion query for two triangles place at different Z in android OpenGLES 3.0.

Here is how I am using:

```
In onSurfaceCreated():
     GLES30.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
     GLES30.glEnable(GLES30.GL_DEPTH_TEST);     // enabling Deoth test

In onDrawFrame(): 
     GLES30.glClear(GLES30.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
     Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
     Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
     Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // translating at some differnt z = 1.0
     drawTriangle(mTriangle1Vertices);                      // method for drawing traingle1

     Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
     Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // other triangle at Z = 0.0

// Occlusion Query for Triangle2
    IntBuffer testBox = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    IntBuffer hasBeenTested = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    IntBuffer theParams = IntBuffer.allocate(1);

    GLES30.glGenQueries(1, testBox);
    int retid = testBox.get(0);
    GLES30.glBeginQuery(GLES30.GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED, retid);

    drawTriangle(mTriangle2Vertices);         // drawing traingle 2 ie at Z = 0.0

    GLES30.glEndQuery(retid);
    int retQuerry = testBox.get(0);
    GLES30.glGetQueryObjectuiv(retid, GLES30.GL_QUERY_RESULT, theParams);

    int isHidden = theParams.get(0);              // THIS IS ALWAYS ZERO even if  I REVERSE the Z- translation of the triangles
    Log.i("occ", " isHiddedn " +  isHidden);        

    GLES30.glDeleteQueries(1, testBox);
```

In `drawTriangle()` method I simply pass color, vertex and MVP uinform to vertex shader.

On my device screen I can see the TRAINGLE 2 is fully occluded by TRIANGLE 1. Also if I reverse the Z-translation other triangle is occluded fully. But still the test results (isHidden) remains same?
Where am I going wrong? How to get perform proper occlusion test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument to `glEndQuery()` is the target, not the query id. This is the same as the first argument to the corresponding `glBeginQuery()`. In your case, it would be:

```
GLES30.glBeginQuery(GLES30.GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED, retid);
drawTriangle(mTriangle2Vertices);
GLES30.glEndQuery(GLES30.GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED);
```